# How do I achieve this ui design in flutter for menu drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

This is the desired design for my app's menu drawer.

[image]

how do I do that vertical line below alerts menu item which runs throughout all sub menu items. that small horizontal line which is left to submenu item is easy. But how do I do that vertical long line?

Comment: Use a VerticalDivider widget, place it in a row

Comment: @Texv it worked. thanks. You can put it as a answer. I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `VerticalDivider` widget and place it in a row :)